# iOS 8 UIScrollView not matching content size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, ios8

I've recently started a new project with iOS 8, I've been trying a few things out with the UIScrollView so I created a new single view project, added the scrollview to the main storyboard, added an view to it and increased the content size, however, the scroll view doesn't scroll through the whole content size. The code is so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIViewController* controllerA = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[[controllerA view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[[controllerA view] setBounds:[[self view] bounds]];

[_comicScrollView addSubview:[controllerA view]];

[_comicScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(640, 480)];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

And the is the final point where the scroll view stops:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlWpY.jpg

Comment: Can you check the frame of the scrollView ? `NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(_comicScrollView.frame));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are setting the content size directly hard coded in viewDidLoad. That will break already if you just rotate the device.

solution is overwrite the

```
- viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    CGRect boundsOfSelf = self.view.bounds;
    _comicScrollView.frame = boundsOfSelf;
    [_comicScrollView.frame setContentSize: boundsOfSelf.size];
    // also resize your controllerA.view here if needed.
}
```

dont ever set frames in viewDidLoad. They don't adjust to anything during the viewController lifetime. PhoneStatusBar, Orientation change and so on. Also this method will work for all phones and pads :)